# How to get the current logged in user object from spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring security version 3.1.4.RELEASE.
How can I access the current logged in user object?

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

returns user name, not user object. So how can I use the returned Username and get the UserDetails object?

I have tried the following code:

```
public UserDetails getLoggedInUser(){

    final Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null && auth.isAuthenticated() && !(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken))
    {
        if(auth.getDetails() !=null)
            System.out.println(auth.getDetails().getClass());
        if( auth.getDetails() instanceof UserDetails)
        {
            System.out.println("UserDetails");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("!UserDetails");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Following is the result:

```
[2015-08-17 19:44:46.738] INFO  http-bio-8443-exec-423   System.out    class org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails 
[2015-08-17 19:44:46.738] INFO  http-bio-8443-exec-423   System.out    !UserDetails
```

AuthenticationFilter class as follows:

```
public class CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY = "j_username";
    public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY = "j_password";
    public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY = "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME";
    private String usernameParameter = SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY;
    private String passwordParameter = SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY;
    private boolean postOnly = true;

    public CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
        super("/j_spring_security_check");
    }

    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (postOnly && !request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
        }

        String username = obtainUsername(request);
        String password = obtainPassword(request);
        if (username == null) {
            username = "";
        }
        if (password == null) {
            password = "";
        }
        username = username.trim();
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

        // Allow subclasses to set the "details" property
        setDetails(request, authRequest);
        if(this.getAuthenticationManager()==null){
            logger.info("Authentication manager is null.");
        } else {
            logger.info("Authentication manager was "+this.getAuthenticationManager().getClass().getName()); 
        }
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }

    protected String obtainPassword(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getParameter(passwordParameter);
    }

    protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getParameter(usernameParameter);
    }

    protected void setDetails(HttpServletRequest request, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest) {
        authRequest.setDetails(authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));
    }

    public void setUsernameParameter(String usernameParameter) {
        this.usernameParameter = usernameParameter;
    }

    public void setPasswordParameter(String passwordParameter) {
        this.passwordParameter = passwordParameter;
    }

    public void setPostOnly(boolean postOnly) {
        this.postOnly = postOnly;
    }

    public final String getUsernameParameter() {
        return usernameParameter;
    }

    public final String getPasswordParameter() {
        return passwordParameter;
    }
}
```

AuthenticationProvider as follows:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public MyUserDetailsService getUserDetailsService() {
        return userDetailsService;
    }

    public void setUserDetailsService(MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails arg0,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken arg1)
            throws AuthenticationException {

    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String arg0,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken arg1)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        return userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(arg0);
    }
}
```

UserDetails class as follows:

```
    public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {       
    private final Map<String, UserDetails> usersList;
    
    public MyUserDetailsService() {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorityList;
        final SimpleGrantedAuthority supervisorAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("supervisor");
        final SimpleGrantedAuthority userAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("user");
        usersList = new TreeMap<String, UserDetails>();

        authorityList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorityList.add(supervisorAuthority);
        authorityList.add(userAuthority);
        usersList.put("admin", new User("admin", "admin", authorityList));

        authorityList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorityList.add(userAuthority);
        usersList.put("peter", new User("peter", "password123", authorityList));

        //probably don't use this in production
        for(Map.Entry<String, UserDetails> user : usersList.entrySet()){
            logger.info(user.getValue().toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserDetails ud = usersList.get(username);
        if (ud != null) {
            logger.info("loadUserByUsername: found match, returning "
                    + ud.getUsername() + ":" + ud.getPassword() + ":"
                    + ud.getAuthorities().toString());
            return new User(ud.getUsername(), ud.getPassword(),
                    ud.getAuthorities());
        }

        logger.info("loadUserByUsername: did not find match, throwing UsernameNotFoundException");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you authenticate your users? What is the AuthenticationProvider, and what is the Filter?

Comment: Ok, you a custom AuthenticationFilter not far from a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. It is common to use a DaoAuthenticationProvider with that. Did you configure `setForcePrincipalAsString(True) ` (or set `forcePrincipalAsString` to true) anywhere?

Comment: @SergeBallesta No I didn't use those methods

Comment: With the shown code and a default (or common) configuration, `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` should return the `User` object provided by `MyUserDetailsService`. You should try to use a debugger to follow a full authentication request (after downloading sources for SpringSecurity)

Comment: Or do you have anything (a filter or ?) that would use the authentication object to set the request Principal to the user name ?

Answer (score 66):

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Returns the current user object. This can be `User`, `UserDetails` or your *custom user* object. 
You will need to cast the return object to `UserDetails` or your own  user object if it is a custom one.

OR you can inject `Authentication` or `Principal` directly in to your controllers.
Principle is your `UserDetails`/custom user object.

Note: `UserDetails` is an interface

Comment: [Also a mkyong how-to w/ slightly more details.](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/get-current-logged-in-username-in-spring-security/)

Comment: How to get the user's id?

Comment: There is a username (String) field in the User/UserDetails class/interface, if your user's id is the username.

Comment: I am getting java.lang.ClassCastException. please help me

Comment: Can any of the objects in between be null?

Answer (score 28):

you can use it like

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
String username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
} else {
String username = principal.toString();
}
```

it is in spring security reference http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#obtaining-information-about-the-current-user

Comment: I am getting username but not user Object.

Comment: I think you have to check the next paragraph after the mentioned above http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#tech-userdetailsservice to get user details using UserDetailsService

Answer (score 11):

You can simply inject the Authentication Interface to your Controller and get the username of the logged in user, like below:

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/username")
    @ResponseBody
    public String currentUserName(Authentication authentication) {
    
        if (authentication != null)
            return authentication.getName();
        else
            return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

You just went one step foo far. `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` returns an `Authentication` object. **You** should know how you authenticated the user, and what can the the concrete class implementing `Authentication`. Assuming it is a subclass of `AbstractAuthenticationToken` (all Spring provided implementation are), and `getDetails()` returns a `UserDetails`, you can just use:

```
AbstractAuthenticationToken auth = (AbstractAuthenticationToken)
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
UserDetails details = (UserDetails) auth.getDetails();
```

Comment: I am getting an instance of WebAuthenticationDetails instead of UserDetails.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html#getDetails()) _getDetails_ is supposed to return additional information about authentication request (like IP addr), so it's not semantically correct to return _UserDetails_ from this method.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem by using `SecurityContextHolder` and `Authentication.getName()` :

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
        
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

String login = authentication.getName();

User user = usersService.getUserByLogin(login);
```

Answer (score 5):

Since version 5.2 you can use [CurrentSecurityContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/annotation/CurrentSecurityContext.html) annotation to get the current user authentication:

```
@GetMapping("/authentication")
public Object authentication(@CurrentSecurityContext(expression="authentication")
                             Authentication authentication) {
    return authentication.getDetails();
}
```

or even:

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String hello(@CurrentSecurityContext(expression="authentication.name")
                    String username) {
    return "Hello, " + username + "!";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class User implements UserDetails {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

}
```

assuming you have a custom user implementing UserDetails class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
class UsersController {

    @GetMapping
    public User fetchUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the attributes of your current user , first go to the class that implements `UserDetails` , more likely its called `UserPrincipal` and write a get method for each attribute like : `getAge()`, seconde go to you HTML  file and write this

```
<span th:text="${#request.userPrincipal.principal.age}> </span>
```

And by the way you dont need to add any ModelAttribute in your controller
Hope it fix the problem , and you can ask me

Comment: You didn't answer the initial question: "how to get the UserDetails object?"

Comment: @GetMapping("update")
    public String updateProfil(Authentication authentication ) {
     User u= userRepository.findByUsername(authentication.getName()).get();
     System.out.println(u.getGender());
     return "update";
    
    }

Comment: `@Controller
public class HomeController {

 @Autowired 
 UserRepository userRepository;
 private UserPrincipalDetailsService userPrincipalDetailsService;
 public HomeController(UserPrincipalDetailsService userPrincipalDetailsService) {
  this.userPrincipalDetailsService=userPrincipalDetailsService;
 }

    @GetMapping("")
    public String updateProfil(Authentication authentication ) {
     User u= userRepository.findByUsername(authentication.getName()).get();
     //you can get anything from the object
     System.out.println(u.getGender());
     return " "; }}

`

Comment: @KhalidTamine this should be either another answer, or an edit to an existing answer, but not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can get current login user via:

1. `@Authenticationprincipal`
2. `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrinciple()`

Comment: This is totally unclear.  Do I need both of those things?  Either/or?  What do I do with those things?  Where do I put them?  Is it in a controller?  A service?  Please provide substantially more detail.  As it stands this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to downcast principal to its implemented class, then you can extract context object which you set in securityContext.

```
 AbstractAuthenticationToken a = (AbstractAuthenticationToken) request.getUserPrincipal();
 UserContext context = (UserContext) a.getPrincipal();
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me with spring boot 2.5

First, define a `User` `Principal` class

```
public class UserPrincipal implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    // other methods ....
}
```

Second, define a `User` class:

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    String username;
    String password;
    //getters ans setters ...
}
```

Third, define a `UserAuth` class:

```
 public class UserAuth {
    
     public String getUsername()
     {
         UserPrincipal principal 
             = (UserPrincipal)SecurityContextHolder
                 .getContext()
                 .getAuthentication()
                 .getPrincipal();
         return principal.getUser().getUsername();
    }
}
```

Finally, you can auto-wire the `UserAuth` class as needed.

Answer (score -1):

So almost every answer seems correct and feasible, kudos to all contributors, but to remove boilerplate code, could be useful and easy:
make an Interface and its implementation that will contain all utility methods, and then simply `@Autowire` that.

```
public interface AuthHelper {
    Authentication getAuthentication();
    public String getName();
    public UserDetails getUserDetails()
}
@Component
public class AuthHelperImpl implements AuthHelper {

    @Override
    public Authentication getAuthentication() {
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    }
    public String getName() {
        return getAuthentication().getName();
    }
    public UserDetails getUserDetails() {
        return (UserDetails) getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }
//and more utilities you need
//you can also cast with UserPrincipal
}
```

now, at controllers:

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {
    @Autowired
    private AuthHelper authHelper;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/username", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String currentUserNameSimple() {
        return authHelper.getName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This may be a good article to read.
The article shows how to get the user information in a Spring application, starting with the common static access mechanism, followed by several better ways to inject the principal.

https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.