# What is the replacement of AuthenticationException.getAuthentication() in Spring4.0.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I was using Spring 3 in my project and now upgraded to Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE.
Now while using `AuthenticationException.getAuthentication()`, it says it is deprecated, but not able to find the alternative. Here is the code:

```
public ModelAndView init(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    AuthenticationException exception = (AuthenticationException) request.getSession().getAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);

    Authentication loginAuthentication = exception.getAuthentication();

    // Set the user name for the change password screen
    return new ModelAndView("common/changePassword", "userName", loginAuthentication.getPrincipal());   
}
```

Also the method `setAuthentication(authentication)` is deprecated.
Is there any alternative for these two methods?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052076/how-to-get-the-current-logged-in-user-object-from-spring-security ?

Comment: I am not sure for alternative but can find reason for deprecation [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/AuthenticationException.html)....and also check [this](http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/04/spring-security-by-example-openid-login.html?showComment=1369334442380#c1072711203002013824) comment for more info

Comment: As NealeU said, relying logic needs re-thinking, but there's '''SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();'''  from https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security

Answer (score 2):

There is no replacement, because this method was a security risk.

The [latest Javadoc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/3.2.x/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/AuthenticationException.java#L67) for the 3.x releases says:

> @deprecated to avoid potential leaking of sensitive information (e.g. through serialization/remoting).

Any code that relied on this will need a little re-thinking.