# Replacement for AuthenticationException.getAuthentication();

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We upgraded our application from Spring & Hibernate 3.x to 4.x. The problem is that AuthenticationException.getAuthentication() has been deprecated now. Can any one suggest any alternative to this.
Below is the code that we were using:

```
public ModelAndView init(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    AuthenticationException exception = (AuthenticationException)request.getSession().getAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);

    Authentication loginAuthentication = exception.getAuthentication();

    //Set the user name for the change password screen
    return new ModelAndView("common/changePassword", "userName", loginAuthentication.getPrincipal());   
}
```

Can someone point me to the replacement for this. Not much is available online.

Comment: See [What is the replacement of AuthenticationException.getAuthentication() in Spring4.0.3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39524178/1553851)

Comment: Already checked that link, no solution there

Comment: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` and `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(Authentication)`.

Comment: @manish: what is the Authentication parameter that you are passing?, also can you explain what exactly you mean by the above 2 lines

Comment: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` is a reliable way to obtain an `Authentication` object for the current security context (thread, `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpSession`, etc.). You asked what is a replacement for `AuthenticationExcpetion.getAuthentication()`, so this is the substitute. `AuthenticationExcpetion` also used to have a `setAuthentication` method. `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(Authent‌​ication)` is the substitute for that.

Comment: Note that Spring Security 4.1 has got rid of `getAuthentication` and `setAuthentication` methods from `AuthenticationException` completely.

Comment: Using this we get a NullPointer Exception because the SecurityContextHolder is null.

Answer (score 1):

If the following piece of code is executed in case of `AuthenticationException` that means the username and password you submitted from login form will be still available in the `HttpServletRequest`. So I think you can get the username from there.

```
public ModelAndView init(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    AuthenticationException exception = (AuthenticationException)request.getSession().getAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);

    String username = request.getParameter("<Name of your username parameter>");

    //Set the user name for the change password screen
    return new ModelAndView("common/changePassword", "userName", username);   
}
```