# Grails spring security getting the logged in user

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am developing an ordering web application and I am new to learning Grails. I used the Spring Security plugin. I haved configured and override the login and register, what I want is to get the currently logged in user to apply an order. Is there a way to do this without using the static belongsTo? Because using this always shows me a dropdown box where I can choose between the users and admins. Am I doing the right approach in getting the logged in user to order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to retrieve the currently authenticated principal is via a static call to the SecurityContextHolder:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
if (!(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
    String currentUserName = authentication.getName();
    return currentUserName;
}
```

**OR**

Inject SpringSecurityService bean, 
like this into controller

```
def springSecurityService
```

and then call

```
def currentPrincipal = springSecurityService.principal

print "The details of current logged in user is" + currentPrincipal
```

For more details follow this link
http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security

[How to get the current logged in user object from spring security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052076/how-to-get-the-current-logged-in-user-object-from-spring-security)

Comment: The easiest way with the plugin is to dependency-inject the `SpringSecurityService` bean, e.g. `def springSecurityService` and call `def currentPrincipal = springSecurityService.principal`